# handling users redirects when login occurs on my document

Tags: javascript, php

Well my question is :

I have my homepage called index.php , and i want to redirect a user when he/she login. But i dont want the user to see the structure of my site .

EX: user does login on `mywebsite.com/index.php` and he will go to `mywebsite.com/users/user0001?`

How can i make the user stay on the same page when he login but with his data as a user.

I have been reading about `htaccess` but i dont really get it , and i dont know how can i use it to solve my problem

Comment: Use `RewriteEngine`. The Apache module mod_rewrite allows you to rewrite URL requests that come into your server and is based on a regular-expression parser

Comment: Beautiful . Picked up a tutorial and it works perfectly Link :http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite